# Why is Stack Overflow page loading infinitely? Says "waiting for careers.stackoverflow.com"

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow, firefox

I'm using Mozilla Firefox 6. Stack Overflow site continues loading infinitely. The spinner shows on the tab button and a message at the bottom "waiting for careers.stackoverflow.com". 
Why doesn't the loading finish?

Comment: I just ran into this today w/ FF 8.0

Comment: Can you tell what exact resource, using Firebug? @Jason - you can give such info too, helping the moderators to find the problem.

Comment: @Shadow: Working on it; the error is sporadic, and I'd need to catch it with firebug's Net page or HTTP Live Headers.

Comment: Hmm. Firebug Net page seems to cause a Heisenbug effect (can no longer observe the problem), but when I disable Firebug Net page, I get stuck on this HTTP request as seen by HTTP Live Headers: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/ad/i/hGjpDOw-hUrWXtK-i7pNfi0-12
)

Comment: @#%@#%@#% Heisenbug! Firebug Net page disabled: problem occurs relatively frequently. Net page enabled: problem goes away (so a stopgap solution is to just enable Firebug net page)

Comment: I had this happen a few days ago with Chrome, but it fixed itself after ten minutes and hasn't recurred.

Comment: Getting a bunch of stuck pages in the past hour.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I think I found what's causing it - that's at least a start.

The main SO page contains three random job offers, for example:

[image]

Under the hood, the code that generates this is located [here](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/ad/js).

As you can see, it contains this part:

```
<img alt=\"\" class=\"impression\" src=\"http://careers.stackoverflow.com/ad/i/ibzx1oA-brrPe6s-hMAPzIA-12\" style=\"display:none\" />
```

That hidden image is most likely tracking beacon meant to track who is viewing what jobs, to prevent same jobs from being displayed again etc.. nothing wrong with that.

Now the question is: why your browser is blocking/choking on that URL? I couldn't reproduce the problem, with none of my browsers, including Firefox 8. I can only assume that one of your add-ons for Firefox is the culprit, try disabling the add-ons one by one until you find it.

Comment: Some broken proxies are known to choke on the `204 No content` HTTP status code, so it may not be an add-on, but a proxy.

Comment: @balpha good point.. can explain blahdiblah comment on the question.